# Calculate a function over all permutations of columns

Tags: matlab, matrix

I have this code:

```
abs(mean(exp(1i*( a(:,1) - a(:,2) ))))
```

where `a` is a *550*-by-*129* double matrix. How can I write code using that code to replace `a(:,1)` with `a(:,2)` and then `a(:,3)` and so on because I need each column to subtract from every other column?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Another method using matrix multiplication:

```
E = exp(1i*a);
result = abs(E.'*(1./E)/size(E,1));
```

Explanation:

You can rewrite the expression

```
exp(1i*( a - b) ))
```

as

```
exp(1i*a)/exp(1i*b)
```

so

```
exp(1i*a)*(1/exp(1i*b))
```

and `mean(x)` is `sum(x)/n`

Using that you can do your task using very fast matrix multiplication.

Result of a comparison between different methods in Octave:

```
Matrix Multiplication:
Elapsed time is 0.0133181 seconds.

BSXFUN:
Elapsed time is 1.33882 seconds.

REPMAT:
Elapsed time is 1.43535 seconds.

FOR LOOP:
Elapsed time is 3.10798 seconds.
```

[Here](http://rextester.com/IAZHP12472) is the code for comparing different methods.

Comment: Matrix multiplication always wins... as long as you have the memory for it :)

Answer (score 3):

Looped, this is an easy trick; let an outer loop run over all indices, and an inner loop as well.

```
a = rand(550,129);
out = zeros(size(a,2),size(a,2));
for ii = 1:size(a,2)
    for jj = 1:size(a,2)
        out(ii,jj) = abs(mean(exp(1i*(a(:,ii)-a(:,jj)))));
    end
end
```

Answer (score 3):

No loops, one line:

```
result = permute(abs(mean(exp(1i*bsxfun(@minus, a, permute(a, [1 3 2]))),1)), [2 3 1]);
```

This computes all pairs of row differences as a 3D array, where the second and third dimensions refer to the two row indices in the original 2D arrays; then applies the required operations along the first dimension; and finally permutes the dimensions to yield a 2D array result.

Answer (score 2):

a bit off-topic, but you can do that with indexing too

```
a = rand(550,129);
c = repmat(1:size(a,2),1,size(a,2));
c(2,:) = imresize(1:size(a,2), [1 length(c)], 'nearest');
out = abs(mean(exp(1i*( a(:,c(1,:)) - a(:,c(2,:)) ))));
out = reshape(out,[size(a,2) size(a,2)]); % 129x129 format
```